# Disable hostname in fastify logs with Pino

Tags: fastify

I've found that Pino offers a mechanism for removing this [through an option called base](https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=base-object) but it seems that's not available through the fastify logging configuration. What's the best way to use the default fastify logger but remove the hostname from all log lines?

As a sample, here's some output with the default fastify logger:

```
{"level":30,"time":1660583707685,"pid":17,"hostname":"goldsky-api-7cf949f758-zzpf2","msg":"Server listening at http://0.0.0.0:80"}
```

I'd like to remove `hostname` which is automatically injected into this log line.

EDIT: the [`FastifyLoggerOptions`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/types/logger.d.ts#L41) don't seem to provide fields for the pino `base` option which means if I try to pass that option, typescript compilation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger option is forwarded to the fastify's pino instance:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: {
    // pino options
    base: false,
  },
})
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})
fastify.inject('/')
```

Comment: yup, looks like typescript users just have to add `@ts-ignore` before passing in `base`.

Answer (score 0):

Or for plain Node.JS set "base" as "null".

```
export const logger = pino({
  base: null,
  level: process.env.PINO_LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
  timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
  formatters: {
    level: (label) => {
      return { level: label.toUpperCase() };
    },
  },
  transport: {
    target: 'pino/file',
    options: { destination: 'logfile.log', append: true},
  },
});
```